# Apache spark selectExpr int value exceeds the maxvalue

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

in our application we use below expression

```
df.selectExpr((col_x*8*6)/(1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 60 * 15))
```

when we use above we get null value due to this part exceed the integer max value `1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 60 * 15`

so we changed above expression to like below and its working

```
df.selectExpr((col_x*8*6)/(1024.0 * 1024.0 * 1024.0 * 60.0 * 15.0))
```

problem is we have thousands of existing expression so is there any configuration handle this integer exceeds max value

Comment: the max value is limited by the size of an integer variable, and you can only change it to long or double. I don't think there's anything you can do to change the size of int.

Comment: Your final result will be of type ```double``` you can cast ```col_x``` to of type ```double```

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast colx to long or double data type inside your expresion.